# Opposition between the LOT vowel and the STRUT vowel

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, accent, ipa

I've noticed that some UK accents have the LOT vowel in words like *nothing*, *none* or *one*, whereas others have the STRUT vowel. The Lexico and Cambridge online dictionaries only give the STRUT pronunciation. Can anyone tell me where in the UK the LOT vowel tends to occur instead? I know that at least some Yorkshire accents have the FOOT vowel in *one*, so it's not a simple north/south divide.

Comment: Is it the British HOT vowel or the American HOT vowel (which would be closer to the British START vowel)? Those are quite different vowels.

Comment: I have known a handful of people with LOT in those words, and I can't say that they had any regional background in common - or indeed any other noteworthy features of their accent...

Comment: Are we agreed on **Strut, Pronunciation:**  Brit. /strʌt/,  U.S. /strət/ - **Lot, Pronunciation:**  Brit. /lɒt/,  U.S. /lɑt/ - **Nothing, Pronunciation:**  Brit. /ˈnʌθɪŋ/,  U.S. /ˈnəθɪŋ/ - **none, Pronunciation:** Brit. /nʌn/, /nɒn/, U.S. /nən/ - **One, Pronunciation:**  Brit. /wʌn/, /wɒn/, U.S. /wən/?

Comment: I'm the OP - for some reason I didn't seem to be able to post from this account yesterday so I used a guest account, which means I can't log back in to respond to the comments. Anyway @PeterShor I meant the British HOT vowel...

Comment: @AakashM Do you think it could be a generational thing then?

Comment: @Greybeard the HOT vowel is OK for me in none and one, but also in nothing. It does not stick out for me at all. Still, the fact that the dictionaries I mentioned only give the STRUT pronunciation suggests that it is somehow nɒn-standard, so I was wondering what the distribution was.

Comment: *The HOT vowel is OK for me in none and one, but also in nothing.* That sounds like "General Central Northern Standard Pronunciation" (http://www.yek.me.uk/centnthpn.html)  I had a friend from Bury (/bʊri/ notˈ/bɛri/) who spoke the same way.

Comment: At the link above, I have just seen *nothing / `nɒθɪŋ / LPD "§"*

Comment: @Greybeard that's a very useful resource, many thanks - so JWL says that the HOT pronunciation is found in certain areas of his "Central Northern" region, while Wells identifies it as "widespread in England among educated speakers, but ... nevertheless judged to fall outside RP". Meanwhile *constable* (with the HOT vowel) makes it into Wells' "General British subvariant" category. I feel the same way about *constable* as I do about the other words, i.e. the HOT version sounds neutral and the STRUT version sounds a bit old fashioned, although I can't swear I never use it.

Comment: @Greybeard You really cannot use dictionaries for this. Compare [*top*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/top) and [*one*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/one).

Answer (score 3):

[Wells (1982](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511611759.003): 261) says:

> *one* is /wɒn/ in parts of the north, rather than the expected /wʊn/ (RP /wʌn/); the /wɒn/ area includes Birmingham, Stoke, Liverpool, Manchester and Sheffield. Further east and north there is indeed /wʊn/, it having in some places displaced traditional-dialect forms such as /jan/. In a somewhat more restricted area, *once*, *among*, *none* and *nothing* may also be encountered with /ɒ/.

[Roach (2009: 162)](https://books.google.com/books?id=dDVR_zh5wkMC&pg=PA162) identifies "the Midlands and north-western England" to be the area in which words such as *one*, *none*, *nothing*, *tongue*, *mongrel*, *constable* are pronounced with /ɒ/.